# Python HTTP Request Binary Data using Requests

Tags: python, http, curl, python-requests, url-parameters

The following code only works in curl. It would be nice if you could tell me why it isnt working in Python using Requests

```
curl 'http://cdcnepal.com/Modules/HOmeMoviesLists/WebService2.asmx/GetShowsByDate' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
 -d '{"portalId":"1","showDate":"26/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}'
```

However in Python with the following code

```
import requests
import json
url = """http://cdcnepal.com/Modules/HOmeMoviesLists/WebService2.asmx/GetShowsByDate"""
headers = {"content-type":["application/json", "charset=UTF-8"]}
payload = {"portalId":"1","showDate":"26/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print r.text
```

Originally the curl request had other content, below, however I realised I could remove several. I'm not sure that is causing the error because the curl request is working. I'm not getting the same response from both the code.

This might be useful. A Curl Requests extracted from Chrome Dev Tools

```
curl 'http://cdcnepal.com/Modules/HOmeMoviesLists/WebService2.asmx/GetShowsByDate'
 -H 'Cookie: OriginalReferrer=https://www.google.com/;
     OriginalURL=http://cdcnepal.com/;
     ASP.NET_SessionId=i5lbnql5hpp0wm1ywyqbywtj;
     VisitCount=4' 
 -H 'Origin: http://cdcnepal.com' 
 -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' 
 -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6' 
 -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3)
     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36' 
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
 -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' 
 -H 'Referer:http://cdcnepal.com/Home.aspx' 
 -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
 -H 'DNT: 1' 
 --data-binary '{"portalId":"1","showDate":"27/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}' --compressed
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `curl` `-d` switch sends a **`POST`** request, but you are using `requests.get()` instead, sending a `GET` request (whose body is ignored).

Make it a POST instead, by using `request.post()`:

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://cdcnepal.com/Modules/HOmeMoviesLists/WebService2.asmx/GetShowsByDate"
headers = {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
payload = {"portalId":"1","showDate":"26/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print r.text
```

You also need to:

1. not use a list for the `content-type` header, there is no support for paramaters being specified separately.
2. Encode your JSON data to a JSON string; `requests` doesn't do this for you. Instead, a dictionary passed to `data` is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data instead.

You can compare the `curl` command with `requests` more easily using http://httpbin.org/post:

```sh
$ curl http://httpbin.org/post \
>  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
>  -d '{"portalId":"1","showDate":"26/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}'

{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"portalId\":\"1\",\"showDate\":\"26/05/2014\",\"flag\":0,\"size\":9}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "58",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.30.0",
    "X-Request-Id": "78d7bb7d-e29b-482b-908a-48d2395a050f"
  },
  "json": {
    "flag": 0,
    "portalId": "1",
    "showDate": "26/05/2014",
    "size": 9
  },
  "origin": "84.92.98.170",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

and

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> headers = {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
>>> payload = {"portalId":"1","showDate":"26/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}
>>> r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
>>> pprint(r.json())
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'{"portalId": "1", "flag": 0, "size": 9, "showDate": "26/05/2014"}',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate, compress',
              u'Connection': u'close',
              u'Content-Length': u'65',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Darwin/13.1.0',
              u'X-Request-Id': u'06d6b542-c279-4898-8701-2c0d502aa36e'},
 u'json': {u'flag': 0,
           u'portalId': u'1',
           u'showDate': u'26/05/2014',
           u'size': 9},
 u'origin': u'84.92.98.170',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```

Both cases show the same `json` dictionary being returned.

If you are using `requests` version 2.4.2 or newer, you can also leave the JSON encoding to the library; it'll set the correct Content-Type header too, if you pass in the data to send as the `json` keyword argument:

```
import requests

url = "http://cdcnepal.com/Modules/HOmeMoviesLists/WebService2.asmx/GetShowsByDate"
payload = {"portalId":"1","showDate":"26/05/2014","flag":0,"size":9}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
print r.text
```

Comment: I tried what you said but I'm getting a error
[{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}]

Even tried adding cUrl's user agent didnt work.. anything else I can try out?

Comment: @ShapNepal: I get the exact same JSON response for your URL as the CURL response. It works for me.

Comment: @ShapNepal: make sure your code matches mine in my answer; if I copy and paste the code at the start of my answer into a Python interactive interpreter it prints out a full JSON response.

Comment: Yes!!, it's working in iPython, funny, I was using Sublime Text 3 and it gave me a error. Thanks guys!